# Where to get libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll for relevant Mingw build?

Tags: c++, mingw, libuv

I'm trying to build a libuv dependant application with the latest Mingw 4.8.4 and resulting binary is asking for libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll.

- I can't use -static (or -static-libgcc) when building due to a number of other dynamically linked libraries which are then being forced to be linked statically
- I can see libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll being lodged in 4.7.0's lib folder, but this is not present in 4.8.4
- Using libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll from Mingw 4.7.0 results in missing entry point for __gxx_personality_sj0 issue
- Tried building Migw as described in README.gcc-4.8.1-4-mingw32, but no libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll appeared

I would really appreciate any clues what to do next. Thank you.

Comment: Check your `MinGW/bin` directory.

Comment: Actually I'd find an answer on MinGW mail list:

Mingw.org distributes GCC that depends on libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll instead. That's what I see in gcc-core-4.8.1-4-mingw32-dll.tar.lzma available from the MinGW site.  Also, there's no GCC 4.8.4 there.

project page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
ML: mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net